# Transaction management across the WAR(S)

Tags: spring-boot, transactions, commit, spring-transactions, rollback

Wanted to understand if the spring boot transaction management works for the REST calls made between API(s) of different WAR(S). For commit, rollback etc to be in sync how should be transaction management used.

Thanks in advance!